# Redis PubSub: Connections timeout

Tags: java, spring, redis, publish-subscribe

Our subscription client connections keeps disconnecting with the following error.

```
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:47)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:36)
at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:210)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.subscribe(JedisConnection.java:2986)
at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer$SubscriptionTask.eventuallyPerformSubscription(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:784)
at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer$SubscriptionTask.run(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:740)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:202)
at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:215)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:340)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getRawObjectMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:285)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedisPubSub.process(BinaryJedisPubSub.java:87)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedisPubSub.proceed(BinaryJedisPubSub.java:82)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.subscribe(BinaryJedis.java:3070)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.subscribe(JedisConnection.java:2983)
... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:196)
... 14 common frames omitted
]
```

**For having permanent connections, we have configured 0 timeout in both client and server.**

Redis Client:

```
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(10);
        poolConfig.setMaxIdle(5);
        poolConfig.setBlockWhenExhausted(true);
        poolConfig.setMinIdle(2);
        poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);

        JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHostName(HOST);
        factory.setPort(PORT);
        factory.setDatabase(Protocol.DEFAULT_DATABASE);
        factory.setPoolConfig(poolConfig);
        factory.setTimeout(0);
        JedisShardInfo shardInfo = new JedisShardInfo(factory.getHostName(), factory.getPort(), 0);
        factory.setShardInfo(shardInfo);

        return factory;
```

Redis Server Config:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG GET client-output-buffer-limit
1) "client-output-buffer-limit"
2) "normal 0 0 0 slave 268435456 67108864 60 pubsub 257949696 134217728 0"
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you check what is the value for the field 'client_recent_max_output_buffer' before and after client disconnects? It's printed as part of info command

Comment: Couldnt find the field in the command:

`ubuntu@prod-redis:~$ redis-cli info clients
# Clients
connected_clients:132
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0
`

Comment: Which version of Redis are you using? Could be that older version doesn't print this